# Use the result of a CASE statement in PL SQL in a concatenation operation

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, case

OK, probably a very simple answer but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here and I didn't find a good illustration on here elsewhere. :) Obviously not a SQL expert by any means but working on it. I'm trying to use the result of a CASE statement as a variable in a concatenation but it's not working. So like:

```
Select
   Thing1,
   Thing2,
   Case 
      When a.business_seg = 'A' then '25'
      ...
      Else ' '
   End as BusinessSegment,
   Thing2 || BusinessSegment as Thing3
FROM A_Table;
```

I know the concatenation works with other fields from the SELECT statement just not using the result from the CASE statement.

Like if I do:

```
Thing2 || Thing1 as Thing3
```

works as expected.

Is this some kind of binding issue where I need to save the result to a table first or something similar???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question, and state what is not working, and show sample table data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In projection you need to use the expression. You cannot use an alias as a value holder.

Here is a solution:

```
Select
   Thing1,
   Thing2,
   Case 
      When a.business_seg = 'A' then '25'
      ...
      Else ' '
   End as BusinessSegment,
   Thing2 || Case 
      When a.business_seg = 'A' then '25'
      ...
      Else ' '
   End as Thing3
FROM A_Table;
```

or via subquery

```
select Thing1, Thing2, Thing2 || BusinessSegment as Thing3 from 
(Select
   Thing1,
   Thing2,
   Case 
      When a.business_seg = 'A' then '25'
      ...
      Else ' '
   End as BusinessSegment
FROM A_Table);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create BusinessSegment in a subsquery first, then you'll be able to concatenate it with Thing2. The issue is that you are concatenating a variable that is not yet defined.

Or if you prefer, you can just concatenate directly, ie. Thing2 || (case when ...)